# How to remove space preceeding list in non-zero parskip environment?

Tags: spacing, enumitem

How can I get space between paragraphs, which I want in a raggedright document with block paragraphs, and avoid extra space before a list that is not preceeded by whitespace?

If I set topsep=-\parskip, the lists are properly not separated from the text immediately above them.  But I also lose the space after the list before the next paragraph.

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{myshortlist}{itemize}{4}

% Attempt 1: lose space after list before next paragraph
%\setlist[myshortlist]{label=\textbullet,nolistsep,topsep=-\parskip}

% Attempt 2: get extra space between list and immediately preceeding text.
\setlist[myshortlist]{label=\textbullet,nolistsep}

\begin{document}
\raggedright\setlength\parskip{\baselineskip}

Want these paragraphs separated by whitespace.

Want these paragraphs separated by whitespace.

Want space before this line, but not between this line and list:
\begin{myshortlist}
  \item one
  \item two
\end{myshortlist}

Want space before this line, but not between this line and list:
\begin{myshortlist}
  \item one
  \item two
\end{myshortlist}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{myshortlist}{itemize}{4}

\makeatletter
\setlist[myshortlist]{label=\textbullet,nolistsep,topsep=-\parskip, after*={\@topsepadd\parskip}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\raggedright\setlength\parskip{\baselineskip}

Want these paragraphs separated by whitespace.

Want these paragraphs separated by whitespace.

Want space before this line, but not between this line and list:
\begin{myshortlist}
  \item one
  \item two
\end{myshortlist}

Want space before this line, but not between this line and list:
\begin{myshortlist}
  \item one
  \item two
\end{myshortlist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I needed!