# Warning with lualatex, enumitem, a custom list, and very big fonts

Tags: koma-script, enumitem

I'm using a custom list that presses out vertical space (see the answer to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/467713/how-to-remove-space-preceeding-list-in-non-zero-parskip-environment)). It's been working fine, till I recently tried it with some very big fonts via scrextend. Now I get the following warning (the output looks fine):

```
Package enumitem Warning: Negative labelwidth. This does not make much
(enumitem)                sense, on input line 24.
```

I've been looking through the enumitem documentation, but don't see how I'm getting a negative labelwidth.

How can I get rid of the warning?

Here's a MWE that demonstrates the warning. I compile with lualatex.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern} % or other scalable font

% without this, there is no warning:
\usepackage[paperwidth=20in,paperheight=10in]{geometry}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\changefontsizes[64pt]{50pt}

\makeatletter
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{mylist}{itemize}{4}
\setlist[mylist]{label=\textbullet,leftmargin=1.8em,%
  nolistsep,labelsep=1em,%
  topsep=-\parskip, after*={\@topsepadd\parskip}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{mylist}
  \item[A] Outer top
    \begin{mylist}
      \item[B] Inner top
      \item[B'] Inner bottom
    \end{mylist}
  \item[A'] Outer bottom
\end{mylist}
\end{document}
```

Comment: add `\showthe\labelwidth`   on line 22 and it will show `> -0.82086pt.` so you want to make that positive, not simply get rid of the warning

Comment: @cfr So am I boxing myself in by specifying both leftmargin and labelsep?  Is there another way to get the same look without specifying leftmargin? Edit: just tried, and I still get the warning without specifying leftmargin.

Comment: You need either the fix-cm package or a scalable font like lmodern for this fontsize.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You are correct. Both those (and anyfontsize, which I thought I needed) got stripped out when I made my MWE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can let `enumitem` calculate the `labelwidth` with `labelwidth=*`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

% without this, there is no warning:
\usepackage[paperwidth=20in,paperheight=10in]{geometry}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\changefontsizes[64pt]{50pt}

\makeatletter
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{mylist}{itemize}{4}
\setlist[mylist]{label=\textbullet,leftmargin=1.8em,%
  nolistsep,labelsep=1em,labelwidth=*,%
  topsep=-\parskip, after*={\@topsepadd\parskip}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\setlength\parskip{0.5\baselineskip}%

\begin{mylist}
  \item[A] Outer top
    \begin{mylist}
      \item[B] Inner top
      \item[B'] Inner bottom
    \end{mylist}
  \item[A'] Outer bottom
\end{mylist}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I will play around with this tonight. As written, I lose some indentation, but maybe I can get that adjusted. Looks like this will be what I need.

Comment: Indeed this does what I want.